# EF Core 5 parameterized constructor: no suitable constructor found when adding DateTime property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a model with a parameterized constructor in EF core project:

```
public record Position {

    public string AccountId {get;}
    public string ContractId {get;}

    // throws exception without private init
    public DateTime CreationDate {get; private init;}

    public Position(string accountId, string contractId, DateTime creationDate) {
        ...
    }

}
```

For some reason EF core does not pick up `creationDate` property in the constructor. If I remove the `private init` method, it throws the exception:

```
No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Position'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'creationDate' in 'Position(string accountId, string contractId, DateTime creationDate)'.
```

I cannot figure out the source of the issue, since their example suggests it is possible:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors

Comment: Check that your `creationDate` or property name does not contain, for example, Cyrillic letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the document states, it is possible to use the constructor if the arguments can be mapped to properties.

The problem is that by default the `CreationDate` is not considered to be a model property. Because as mentioned in the [Included and excluded properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#included-and-excluded-properties) section:

> By convention, all **public** properties **with a getter and a setter** will be included in the model.

All your properties are get only, so they are not automatically included in the model, so you have to do that manually, e.g.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Position>().Property(e => e.CreationDate);
```

If you are wondering why `CreationDate` and not the other two, it's because most likely you already included them in the model by configuring them to compose the PK of the entity, i.e. something like this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Position>().HasKey(e => new { e.AccountId, e.ContractId });
```

also includes `AccountId` and `ContractId` w/o explicit `.Property` call.

In general it's not a good idea to use get only properties in EF data models. Neither C#9 record types. Simple classes with get/set properties, this is supposed to be *data model*, not business/domain model with applied OO principles like encapsulation etc.

Comment: Right. I should have read it more carefully. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding the use of getters/setters -- I'm following the DDD principles and most of my models are read-only (meaning that object should be immutable after writing).  That's why I don't want any setters.